# Incorrect e-mail recipients in functional test

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing, swiftmailer

A functional test of a process that sends an e-mail with two recipients (one To:, one Cc:) incorrectly claims same recipient as both To: and Cc.

In dev environment the process indicated in the test below sends an e-mail to jmelanzane@bogus.info with a Cc to admin@bogus.info.  (Stepping through the process in test debug mode confirms correct recipients.) Yet the test below fails. Replacing the To: recipient with admin@bogus.info allows the test to fully succeed.

#### console output

Output with `print_r($recipient);` in mailer process during test.

```
PHPUnit 4.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\app\phpunit.xml.dist

FArray
(
    [0] => jmelanzane@bogus.info
)


Time: 4.5 seconds, Memory: 26.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Truckee\MatchingBundle\Tests\Controller\AdminMailerTest::testActivateOrganizationEmail
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'jmelanzane@bogus.info'
+'admin@bogus.info'
```

#### config_test.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    logging: true
```

#### config_dev.yml

```
swiftmailer:
#    disable_delivery:  true
#    delivery_address: admin@bogus.info
```

#### test

```
public function testActivateOrganizationEmail()
{
    $crawler = $this->login('admin');
    $this->client->followRedirects(false);
    $link = $crawler->selectLink('Accept organization')->link();
    $crawler = $this->client->click($link);
    $mailCollector = $this->client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
    $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

    $collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
    $message = $collectedMessages[0];

    $this->assertEquals('jmelanzane@bogus.info', key($message->getTo()));
    $this->assertEquals('admin@bogus.info', key($message->getCc()));
}
```

#### Edit - the process.

In this instance, there is a single element jmelanzane@bogus.info in `$to` and a single element admin@bogus.info in `$this->adminRecipients`.

```
public function activateOrgMail($organization, $to)
{
    $recipient = [];
    foreach ($to as $user) {
        $recipient[] = $this->getAddressee($user);
    }
    $cc = $this->adminRecipients();
    if (!empty($recipient)) {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Organization now active')
                ->setFrom($this->parameters['address'])
                ->setTo($recipient[0])
                ->setCc($cc)
                ->setContentType('text/html')
                ->setBody(
                $this->twig->render(
                        'activated_org', array(
                    'organization' => $organization,
                    'recipient' => $recipient,
                        ), 'text/html'
                )
                )
        ;

        return $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

    private function adminRecipients()
    {
        $em = $this->em;
        $admins = $em->getRepository("TruckeeMatchingBundle:Admin")->findBy(['locked' => false]);
        $adminEmail = [];
        foreach ($admins as $admin) {
            $email = $admin->getEmail();
            $adminEmail[] = $email;
        }

        return $adminEmail;
    }
```

Comment: You should edit your original quesion if you want to improve it.

Comment: Is the app sending the messages to the correct recipients? Could it be possible that actually the app is failing?

Comment: In neither of the questions you have posted do you show how/where the to and cc fields are set. I have flagged the other question as a duplicate to be removed, you should always edit a question rather than re-posting. Please show logic that sets the recipients in the email and also show what values they are actually set to in the unit test so that we can investigate

Comment: @Scriptable Process is added above.  I thought this was really a different question from its predecessor.  Clarifying it I thought would have been misleading. There I learned that there was no miscount by the test, only by me. Here there appears to be a failure to properly account for type of recipient. Shall I delete the previous question?

Comment: i would remove previous question if it was me, upto you. seems too similar

Comment: @acontell Outside of test environment all the correct recipients receive e-mail. In the test environment, the mailer process assigns recipients correctly.  I've not stepped through in an effort to see where reassignment occurs.

Comment: @geoB is the method `getAddressee` returning the correct address (jmelanzane@bogus.info)?

Comment: @acontell The console output shows the result of `print_r($recipient)`, which is the result of `$this->getAddressee($user)`.  That is indeed jmelanzane@bogus.info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARRRGGHHH! It's the ever-popular uncleared cache problem.  In this case, however, one needs to clear the test cache!  Once cleared, tests succeed as expected.